# Programmatically create tabs in MSTeams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to discover if it is possible using Powershell, Graph API or similar to create a Microsoft Teams tab (say with Pllanner or OneNote app associated with it) for every channel in a Team without needing to manually create it for every channel in a Team ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. It's definitely on the roadmap, but we don't have a date to share publicly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a beta API endpoint to [add a tab to channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0) but it is not yet documented.

Answer (score 2):

[Configure the built in tab types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs)

This is the way to do it and it is GA and not a beta endpoint anymore . Also use [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to try and test things out. Enjoy!